# Python - BeautifulSoup - NoneType being returned; Value Definitely Exists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

UPDATE: I've copied all of my code in now. I'm not a programmer, so it probably isn't formatted correct, etc. The PRINT commands at the end are just to test that I'm actually getting some kind of output, I'm planning on writing to a MySQL database once I have everything running fine.

---

I'm trying to scrape some horse racing details from the URL below. I've written some code which scrapes race details - horse names, times, etc - and for the most part, it's working fine.

For some reason though, when it parses the URL in the code below, it's returning a `NoneType` error after returning about 2/3's of the entries (once it hits the 20:05 race at Lingfield).

I've had a look at the source and as far as I can see, there is text in the Div `FastResult__item` (inside a  tag). And the code is returning vales for the other Winning Trainers (also works if I change the date in the URL).

I'm stumped as to why it's returning None, instead of the expected value of `Winning Trainer: Simon Crisford`. Any help would be appreciated - I'm by no means an expert at using Python, so go easy.

Code (copied all of my code in now):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://myracing.com/results/2019-08-03/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
race_listings = soup.find_all("article", class_="FastResult")
for a in race_listings:
    a_meeting = a.find("h3", class_="FastResult__title")
    a_time = a.find("h3", class_="FastResult__title")
    a_draw = a.find("span", class_="FastResult__draw_no").text.strip()
    a_winning_horse = a.find("span", class_="FastResult__horse-name")
    for div in a_winning_horse("sup", {'class':'Racecard__sup-text'}):
        div.decompose()
    a_winning_jockey = a.find("span", class_="FastResult__jockey-name")
    for div in a_winning_jockey("sup", {'class':'Racecard__sup-text'}):
        div.decompose()
    a_winning_trainer = a.find("div", class_="FastResult__item")
print(a_meeting.text[6:].strip())
print(a_time.text[0:6].strip())
print(a_draw.strip("()"))
print(a_winning_horse.text.strip())
print(a_winning_jockey.text[3:].strip())
print(a_winning_trainer.text.strip())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andyjarvis/Documents/Python/horse_predictor_v2.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(a_winning_trainer.text.strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we cannot reproduce your results with what you've provided.

Comment: `a.find("div", class_="FastResult__item")` here is `a` is unknown for us.

Comment: Please share a code snippet that can be reproduced on our end.

Comment: Are you sure that that element isn't being dynamically loaded after the page loads?

Comment: I think there is a bad HTML sequence. Double closing of the ordered list.

Comment: Apologies - I've copied all of my code in now.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to 'fix' this, basically by ignoring it. I think there's an issue with the website, as I'm able to pull most of the information I need. Just seems to be this one trainer that's holding the whole thing up.

I entered the following code, under the 'a_winning_trainer =' line and I'm able to continue:

```
if a_winning_trainer is None:
    continue
```

Cheers